# Keras and Tensorflow: Saving non-sequential model weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-3.6

(I'm using Tensorflow 1.8.0 ...)

The [documentation from Keras on how to save a model](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model) mentions no difference between saving a sequential model vs. one created from the functional API. But, all of the following blocks of code fail:

```
import tensorflow as tf
net = tf.keras.models.Model()
net.save('file')
```

or

```
import tensorflow as tf
net = tf.keras.models.Model()
print(net.to_json())
```

or

```
import tensorflow as tf
net = tf.keras.models.Model()
print(net.to_yaml())
```

or

```
import tensorflow as tf
net = tf.keras.models.Model()
print(net.get_config())
```

They raise a `NotImplementedError`. In the Keras module, the relevant lines are

```
if not self._is_graph_network:
  raise NotImplementedError
```

which shows up in `.save` and `get_config` (the latter is also called by `to_json` and `to_yaml`.

The only thing that DOES work is the following

```
import tensorflow as tf
net = tf.keras.models.Model()
net.save_weights('file')
```

in which case the weights are saved successfully and can be successfully loaded with `net.load_weights`.

However, replacing the second line of the above blocks of code, `net = tf.keras.models.Model()`, with `net = tf.keras.models.Sequential()`, making net a sequential model, allows everything above to work.

Is it really not possible to save the structure of a Keras model made with the functional API (using `Model` rather than `Sequential`)? Right now, can we only save weights?

Comment: Have you considered that all your models are empty, and that is why saving fails?

Comment: I haven't actually, which is ironic since I just answered a question on that topic. I'll try it out with some variables and update. Thank you!

Comment: You don't have to try, we know that saving a Model works, I do it every day, your claim that this somehow is not implemented is ridiculous.

Comment: The claim that Keras raises a `NotImplementedError` is not ridiculous but is repeatable and verifiable. To be honest, it's a misleading error.

Comment: But that is only because the model is empty, there is nothing to save. You directly ask if saving Model is possible.

Comment: And that was my question, not a claim. You answered it anyway, and I also think it's worth mentioning that the current error is misleading, but at this point it seems like the rest of this should go to the chat. :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course its possible to save Model, all your examples have an empty Model, whcih makes no sense to save. Keras' author simply did not implement that case.

If you test with a non-empty Model you will see that saving works perfectly. We use it every day.

Comment: I have the same issue. And with normal model. I can fit this model and evaluate it, but can't save it :(

Comment: @RedEyed Them make a new question, just saying I also have this problem is not really useful. Details matter.